# How to pass string and file as input for form parameters in a POST method using Karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to call a POST method which accepts the below form parameters

Path – A string specifying the path
FileName - A binary file
Media Type: multipart/form-data

Below code helps with the binary file part
Given multipart file xxx= { read: 'classpath:xxx', filename: 'xxx'}

However, in the same request I need to pass the string parameter as well.

Please suggest a way.

Thanks,
Kanika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `multipart field` with `multipart file`, refer to this [demo example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature#L34) also.

```
Given multipart file xxx = { read: 'classpath:xxx', filename: 'xxx' }
And multipart field yyy = 'myvalue'
```